# Is there ever an instance where one can omit the subject in English?

Tags: grammar, commas, subjects

In a sentence like:

> I am an artist, (I) enjoy giving art lessons and I've currently got
> lots of time on my hands

Is the second 'I' necessary?

Comment: It's fine to say: **I'm an artist, enjoy giving art lessons and have lots of time on my hands.** You can decide from the context on whether you want to repeat **I**. **I met John at the library, gave him my notes and (I or he) then left for the airport.**

Comment: [Imperatives](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-imperative)  do not require the subject; e.g. **Go** to your room and **don't leave** until **you have apologized**.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the I in your example because it is a *list*.

For example:

- I have a car, I have a bike, and I have a skateboard.

This would normally be said as:

- I have a car, a bike, and a skateboard.

List items sometimes get presented in writing this way:

> I have:
>
> - a car
> - a bike
> - a skateboard

Any of the list items in this example could be bolted onto the opening "I have", so when spoken there is no need to repeat it.